# comparing between two lists to decrypt a txt file

Tags: python

Blessings,

I have a text file which needs to be decrypted,

It contains the following:

'Puackich, hvhnkrally oaths phufhck. All ymr nhhd is Pykemn.'
J.U.U.U Kmltin.
mmps iks nmk eio; ---> hkmu

The key to decrypt is this :

if the text holds the value of the following letters in the list >
encrypted = ["a", "b", "d", "m", "f", "g", "r", "y", "i"]

it should be changed to the following >
decrypted = ["m", "y", "c", "a", "t", "i", "s", "b", "g"]

while encrypted[1] == decrypted[1] and so forth

what I tried so far

```
encrypted = ["a", "b", "d", "m", "f", "g", "r", "y", "i"]
decrypted = ["m", "y", "c", "a", "t", "i", "s", "b", "g"]

new = []
counter = 0
x = len(encrypted)
with open("encrypt.txt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for i in lines: # will go over words in text
        for b in i: # will go over letters in text
            if b == encrypted[counter]: 
                counter += 1
                new.append[b]
                if counter == x + 1:
                    break
                else:
                    pass
print(new)
```

Comment: to answer the question in the title: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip .

Comment: What problem are you facing?

Comment: that seems very convoluted with all the nested for loops. The current error is because your counter is only incremented if you match ```b == encrypted[counter]```

Comment: This does not work for what I am trying to do but I appreciate the help :) 
I honestly didn't know how to write in the title, guess I should have been more precise.

Comment: @experimentunit1998X I just noticed and changed it accordingly, now it prints ['a', 'd'] 
instead of ['a'] only

Comment: Sadly, I do not fully understand what sam has written.. I am just not there yet,
Care to explain? :)

Comment: your code current checks if a char matches a char from encrypted, and appends the encrypted char to new. you need to append the decrypted char instead. You also need to consider what to do with the chars that do not exist in the encrypted list. what Samwise did was replace the chars in the string with the decrypted chars, not touching the chars that were not encrypted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the approach I'd suggest:

```
encrypted = "abdmfgryi"
decrypted = "mycatisbg"
lookup = dict(zip(
    encrypted + encrypted.upper(),
    decrypted + decrypted.upper()
))

msg = (
    "'Puackich, hvhnkrally oaths phufhck. All ymr nhhd is Pykemn.' "
    "J.U.U.U Kmltin. mmps iks nmk eio; ---> hkmu"
)

print(''.join(lookup.get(c, c) for c in msg))
```

The `lookup` dict is created by zipping the encrypted and decrypted alphabets together into key: value pairs, producing:

```
{'a': 'm', 'b': 'y', 'd': 'c', 'm': 'a', 'f': 't', 'g': 'i', 'r': 's', 'y': 'b', 'i': 'g', 'A': 'M', 'B': 'Y', 'D': 'C', 'M': 'A', 'F': 'T', 'G': 'I', 'R': 'S', 'Y': 'B', 'I': 'G'}
```

Given this dict you can easily translate each encrypted letter to its corresponding letter, yielding the output:

```
'Pumckgch, hvhnksmllb omths phuthck. Mll bas nhhc gs Pbkean.' J.U.U.U Kaltgn. aaps gks nak ego; ---> hkau
```

which doesn't look very decrypted to me, but is the "correct" output given your cipher key.

A better cipher key might be:

```
encrypted = "ehkmortu"
decrypted = "hetomukr"
```

which yields the output:

```
'Practice, eventually makes perfect. All you need is Python.' J.R.R.R Tolkin. oops its not him; ---> etor
```

Comment: If a letter is found it should be appended to a new list, I will try to go over what you just gave me and see what can be found :)

Comment: A better cipher might be `"ehkmortu"` -> `"hetomukr"`...

Comment: wow. how did you actually find the correct cipher key to get that output in that short of a time? i m impressed

Comment: It's pretty easy when you have the hint that not every letter is different.  :)

Comment: Gratitude Sam! :)

Comment: @EllieHodjayev Feel free to ask questions if you're not sure how the code works -- there are really only two lines of code so there's hopefully not a lot to explain, but you have to ask specific questions to get good answers.  :)

Comment: need to google and study for those 2 methods you used .join and .get,

care to explain what the (c, c) means?

This is for our python class :)

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_dictionary_get.asp get(c, c) searches the dictionary for the key, c, if the key does not exist, return c. where c is a char from msg

Comment: It's not accessing the lists directly, it's using the `lookup` dictionary that I built from the lists.  The dictionary maps each encrypted letter to the corresponding decrypted letter.  `lookup.get(c)` returns the decrypted value of `c`.  `lookup.get(c, c)` returns the decrypted value of `c`, with a default of `c` if there is no decrypted value.

Comment: how does (c, c) access our lists?

Comment: `(c, c)` is just the two arguments to the `lookup.get` function.  The first is the key to look up, the second is the default value if the key isn't present.  In this case, the two arguments are the same thing (we want to use the original letter `c` if it's not present in `lookup`).

Comment: Try running the code and adding something like `print("The decrypted value of 'm' is:", lookup.get("m"))`.  Look at what that prints and see if you can work out why it prints that -- then you'll have a better understanding of what that more complicated final line of code does.  :)

Comment: I got it, thanks!..
All the best.